# gas furnace will not come back on

Tags: central-heating

our goodman gas furnace fires up but when the temperature drops and it should come back on it doesn't unless we hit the reset switch.  Repairman has been out and changed the breaker and thermostat.  what else can it be?

Comment: What's the model number?  Is it making any attempt to start?  Does it display any error codes, or have any blinking lights on the control board?

Comment: The sensor on my forced air fan, in the burn box, got old and sticky. Sometimes furnace would come on, sometimes the diaphragm was too cold to allow contact and furnace ignition. I fixed it by running an alligator clip across the two contacts, and buying a Carbon Monoxide monitor. Once Spring comes along, I'll replace the faulty pressure sensor.

Comment: Which reset switch are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

The most common reason is the flame sensor rod is dirty. If this is the problem, then remove the flame sensor rod and gently clean it with steel wool or a dollar bill. Flame sensor rods need to conduct electricity, but if the rod gets coated with dirt then it insulates the flame sensor rod and electricity cannot conduct anymore. Flame sensor rods tend to get dirty more quickly when the furnace is located in the laundry room because the air in the laundry room tends to have more dust.

Comment: Are you referring to the thermocouple probe?